# How are java's standard networking API different from netty?

Tags: java, netty

So im trying to figure out how java's standard networking work different from netty's.

```
public TCPClientDemo() throws Exception {

    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9234);
    String serverHostName = "localhost";

    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);

    String message = "Message \n";

    printStream.print(message);

    System.out.println("Message sent");

    message = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("Message received from server: " + message);

}
```

Here above i have a simple TCP client written from java's default networking framework. Since this client works in a synchronous (IO) fashion will the `printStream.print(message);` method block our current thread, meaning that `println("Message sent")` will not print until our message has actually been sent?

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Netty rocks!", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    System.out.println("Message sent");
}
```

The above example shows how we send in asynchronous fashion in netty. Now here i would assume that `ctx.writeAndFlush()` might actually have not sent the message even if we reach `println("Message sent")` or even returned the `channelActive()` method because of asynchrony? So this essentially would be the opposite of the first example where our code will not continue until the message has actually been sent?